# Keyboard shortcut to delete character under/after cursor in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

suppose I have `Hello World` on a line in vscode, and the cursor is at the beginning of the line.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to delete the characters under (or after, not sure) the cursor?

For example, if `foo` is the shortcut, then for the above case, pressing `foo` 3 times will result in `lo World`, since we deleted the character under cursor 3 times.

note: this is handy if you want to delete a part of a word without first selecting it and pressing `backspace`, in this way you can place the cursor at the start and press the shortcut until all the unwanted characters are gone.

Comment: The `delete` key doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Mark this might seem stupid, but I'm new to vscode and didn't know about it. Please post it as an answer, it works :)

Comment: Now try to find the key binding, if there is one, to remove the word right of the cursor

Comment: @rioV8 I don't understand what do you mean, can you clarify please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I looked to see if this was a duplicate, but didn't find anything in a reasonable amount of time, so...]

You can use the <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the character after the cursor if using the line style cursor or "at" the cursor if using the `block` or `underline` styles.

Cursor styles can be controlled by the setting:

`Editor: Cursor Style`

Comment: yeah I searched well before asking, but maybe bcz its somewhat obvious I didn't see it. Thx :)